# opencv ruby rgb histogram

Tags: c++, ruby, opencv

I am trying to use OpenCV to compare two RGB image histograms, and for this I want to create a CVHistogram in Ruby. I am not sure about the params, as I have got an error with this code:

```
iplimg = OpenCV::IplImage.decode_image(open(icon).read)
dim = 3
sizes = [8,8,8]
ranges = [[0, 255],[0, 255],[0, 255]]
hist = OpenCV::CvHistogram.new(dim, sizes, OpenCV::CV_HIST_ARRAY, ranges, true)
h = hist.calc_hist([iplimg]) # produce error below
```

Here is the error:

> /tmp/opencv-tLdZ/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:698: error:
>   (-5) Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat (OpenCV::CvStsBadArg)

Is this the right way ?

Comment: Rather than forcing us to figure out what the error is, please copy-paste the error message (in full) into the question.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it to paste the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
iplimg = OpenCV::IplImage.decode_image(open(icon).read) # RGB image

b, g, r = iplimg.split # Split RGB image to 1ch image array [b, g, r]

dim = 3
sizes = [8,8,8]
ranges = [[0, 255],[0, 255],[0, 255]]
hist = OpenCV::CvHistogram.new(dim, sizes, OpenCV::CV_HIST_ARRAY, ranges, true)
h = hist.calc_hist([r, g, b])
```